# Why UIBarButtonItem text color alpha is 0?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I create a custom view with a UIToolbar, and a UIBarButtonItem as title.

This is I want:

[image]

And this is what actually display:

[image]

The title is gone. I found the alpha value of UIButtonLabel text color is 0:

[image]

Does anybody have any idea about why this happened and how to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: check your navigation bar tint color

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give a title attribute of your navigation bar. I set below title attribute of default navigation bar if you used any custom navigation bar then set that navigation bar in below code.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.black]
```